# How to add this math symbol "^" in my .cwl?

Tags: texstudio

When I use this math symbol "^" in tikzpicture to draw a plot, the texstudio doesn't recognize. How to add this symbol in my .cwl file?

Comment: You mean \hat or \widehat?

Comment: Ι mean the math symbol of power to calculate.

Comment: IIRC, that would be `\^`.  Technically, there is no such symbol in math, and you should never use it when calculating.

Comment: In this case what can I do? 
`\begin{tikzpicture} \draw plot[domain=1:3] {\x, (\x)^5}; \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'TeXstudio doesn't recognize'? Is the syntax highlighting wrong, or autocomplete doesn't work, or something else?

Comment: This command is highlighted as a "math command out of math mode", while it is working correctly.

Comment: Tikz used to translate `\x^5` as `exp(5*log(\x))` or `pow(\x,5)`.. I understand it now assumes integer exponents and will translate `\x^5` as `\x*\x*\x*\x*\x` which is how you should have written it, so no difference. OTOH, `$ax^2+bx+c$` should be written as `(a*x+b)*x+c` which is both faster and more accurate.

Comment: If it indeed works as intended then this is a bug in the TeXstudio syntax checker, you could open an issue on https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues if you want so the developers can address it.

Comment: For now, I don't have an account, but when I will create one I will inform them. Thank you in advance!